# Can't declare the viewmodel in XAML for this code

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, mvvm

I've reviewed as many 'how to declare the viewmodel in XAML' posts I can and still can't figure this out.  I'm using the simple program below to learn the basics regarding binding and this code works.  When I click to insert(add) items, the listbox automatically reflects that change, as well as when I clear the list.

See my question(s) after the code.

Model

```
Namespace MVVM3
  Public Class MyListItem
    Public Property MyListItemID() As Integer
    Public Property Name() As String
  End Class
End Namespace
```

ViewModel

```
Namespace MVVM3
  Public Class ViewModel
    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

    Public Property allIdeas() As New ObservableCollection(Of MyListItem)

    Public Sub New()
      For index = 0 To 9
        Dim anItem As New MyListItem
        anItem.Name = "Idea " & index
        allIdeas.Add(anItem)
      Next
    End Sub

    Public Sub InsertAnItem()
      Dim anItem As New MyListItem
      anItem.Name = "Item " & allIdeas.Count()
      allIdeas.Add(anItem)
      NotifyPropertyChanged("allIdeas")
    End Sub

    Public Sub ClearStoredList()
      allIdeas.Clear()
      NotifyPropertyChanged("allIdeas")
    End Sub

    Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler _
        Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

    Public Sub NotifyPropertyChanged(ByVal propertyName As String)
      RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName))
    End Sub
  End Class

End Namespace
```

View

```
<Window x:Class="MVVM3.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:mvvm3"
        Title="MainWindow"  SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
        >

  <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
    <Button Margin="25" Content="Insert an item" Click="InsertAnItem_Click"/>
    <Button Margin="25" Content="Clear stored list" Click="ClearStoredList_Click"/>
    <ListBox Name="listBox3" ItemsSource="{Binding allIdeas}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" Height="100">
    </ListBox>
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Code Behind

```
Namespace MVVM3
  Partial Class MainWindow
    Private vm = New ViewModel

    Sub New()
      InitializeComponent()
      DataContext = vm
    End Sub

    Private Sub InsertAnItem_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
      vm.InsertAnItem()
    End Sub

    Private Sub ClearStoredList_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
      vm.ClearStoredList()
    End Sub
  End Class
End Namespace
```

I want to move the ViewModel declaration into XAML to eliminate code behind. If I comment out `DataContext = vm`, no matter what method I've followed from various posts, the binding no longer updates the listbox.

The following changes result in the listbox showing the initial assignment that takes place in ViewModel.New, but after that no changes are reflected:

```
<Window x:Class="MVVM3.MainWindow"
  ...
  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:mvvm3"
  xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:mvvm3.MVVM3"
  ...
  >

  <Window.DataContext>
    <vm:ViewModel/>
  </Window.DataContext>
```

What am I missing?  Is it a namespace problem?

I'm hoping to move on to Commands and ViewModel locators, but I don't see how I can do that until I understand this.

Comment: How you have replaced this code ` vm.InsertAnItem()` after XAML declaration ? Or, after XAML declaration how you are inserting ?

Comment: Have you tried setting the binding mode? I dont see any... but the underlying property must implement `IPropertyNotifyPropertyChanged` and currently `allIdeas` does not.

Comment: `INotifyPropertyChanged`, typo...

Comment: @AnjumSKhan I hadn't replaced that code because I was thinking the `Private vm = New ViewModel` was still in place, but now you mention that, I guess that insert and clear operation is operating on a different instance, isn't it? I was trying to transition one step at a time eliminating the code behind, but I guess I have to change the click methods as well.  Should I use routed or ICommand, or something else?

Comment: `ICommand`... thats proper.

Comment: @Zaggler I have INotifyPropertyChanged in the ViewModel and it does work when the code behind is setting the DataContext.  Is that implementation incorrect?  On that topic, I saw other examples where INPC was on the model, but since INPC was working on my ViewModel at this time I figured I was OK for now.  I intend to work through the INPC on the model later.  But does that respond to your query?

Comment: @Zaggler Will work on ICommand then.  I had actually started that earlier today when my whole project 'blew up'.  So I started over and then disappointingly got stuck again on this XAML declaration of the view model.

Comment: When you declare the view model in XAML you can still access it in code behind by casting the value of the DataContext property, e.g. (C#): `var vm = (ViewModel)DataContext;`.

Comment: Just a comment (not related to your question), but you don't need to raise the property changed event when adding/inserting/deleting items of an `ObservableCollection`.

Comment: @Clemens Your comment is actually the answer to my issue; whether I expressed my question properly or not is another matter.  But you have shown me how I can command the ViewModel from code behind, which is not ultimately what I need to do, but was important for me to be able to see the ViewModel successfully declared in XAML.  So, thanks so much.

Comment: @AndrewStephens Thanks for that.  Nowhere I was reading made that obviously clear.  As you suggested, I commented the line out and sure enough as you say, it still works.  So what do we use NPC for with an ObservableCollection?

Comment: @Alan You are right. Now, `Private vm = New ViewModel` is not needed. You can the `viewmodel` instance using `DataContext` property.

Comment: @Alan the OC raises its own "collection changed" events during Add(), Clear(), etc., which all WPF "list" controls are designed to respond to. When you create an OC in your VM's constructor (or the property declaration, as you've done) then you don't need to use the INPC pattern - as long as your VM code only manipulates its items (Add, Clear, ...). However if you were to re-assign the property (`allIdeas = New ObservableCollection...`) then you *would* need to use INPC to notify the bound control that the property's value had changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you declare an instance of the ViewModel class in XAML, you may access it in code behind by casting the value of the `DataContext` property to the ViewModel type:

```
Partial Class MainWindow
    Sub New()
       InitializeComponent()
    End Sub

    Private Sub InsertAnItem_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
        CType(DataContext, ViewModel).InsertAnItem()
    End Sub

    Private Sub ClearStoredList_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
        CType(DataContext, ViewModel).ClearStoredList()
    End Sub
End Class
```